How to handle & fix Garbage Data?
Problem state
I have a template class called Group which can access unauthorized places in memory. The member variable Group<T>::Items points to serine of locations on the heap that stores a sequence of data such as std::vector<T> (C++ Built-in structure). Data can be manipulated to fit a dynamic size; The member function Group<T>::push(T) is for adding a new item, and the member function Group& Group<T>::operator*(int) can make copies and store them in Group<T >::Items by passing a specific like list() in python or it should work this way.
Here is the class hierarchy in code:
template <typename T>
class Group
{
private:
    T* Items; int length;
public:
    Group() : length(0)
    {
        Items = new(std::nothrow) T[0];
    }
    ~Group()
    {
        delete[] Items; Items = nullptr;
    }

    void push(T ValuetoPush)
    {
        T* BufferAddress = new(std::nothrow) T[length + 1]; // allcatoin new heep's place for data 
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++) BufferAddress[i] = Items[i]; // copy data to the new place from the current.
        /* add the new item to the new place, then make it the current place.*/
        BufferAddress[length++] = ValuetoPush; Items = BufferAddress;
    }

    Group& operator*(int scalar)
    {
        Group* result = new Group;
        for(int i=0; i<scalar; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<length; j++) result->push(Items[j]);
        }
        return *result;
    } 
};

the problem
Now the key point is that when applying Group& Group<Group<int>>::operator*(int) to a nested (Group<Group<int>>&) object (it is similar to the main idea of arrays or lists 2d), when I run the executable, it terminates with a segmentation fault error sometimes it returns a primitive Group<Group<int>>& object which stores garbage in the first positions which is not related to my program and the command What is actually uncommon is that all operations performed after that (if the program passes without error) are correct, which makes matters worse, obviously this means there are memory allocation errors and of course I guess Group stores wrong data positions after entering the operation.
I've debugged the code several times trying to figure out what made the memory or the object behave this way.
Here is the faulty code:
int main()
{
    Group<int> A;
    A.push(1); A.push(2); A.push(3);
    
    Group<Group<int>> B;
    B.push(A * 3);
    B = B * 3; // now B = [[- <Lablablala>, <Lablablala>, - <Lablablala>, <Lablablala>, ...],
               //          [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 
               //          [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]] or it raise an error
}

so I want to do this:
B = B * 3;

std::cout << "<B>:[[" << B[0][0] << ',' << B[0][1] << ',' << B[0][2] << "]," << std::endl;
          << "     [" << B[1][0] << ',' << B[1][1] << ',' << B[1][2] << "]," << std::endl;
          << "     [" << B[2][0] << ',' << B[2][1] << ',' << B[2][2] << "]]" << std::endl;

<B>:[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
     [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
     [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]]


Do you have operator= overloaded in Group class?

Recommended reading: What is the rule of three?

T* Items; int length; -- Why not simply use std::vector<T> Items;?  Also, your code has issues with a two line program: int main() { Group<int> g1;  Group<int> g2 = g1; }.  This is related to the lack of the "rule of 3" mentioned earlier.  You shouldn't be trying to do "complex" things like nesting the classes if the underlying class has these issues.

aside from you leaking memory like crazy, consider this: your B.push(A * 3) creates one of your Group things, passes it as a parameter, which I guess copies it, and then destructs it. Since you're using synthesized copy constructors for this, the Items pointer is simply copied, so when the parameter is destructed it gets deallocated, and then the pointer in the copy points "nowhere".

std::vector (C++ Built-in structure) -- If "built-in" means that vector is somehow hard-wired into C++, it is not.  The std::vector is a class, no different if you were to write it yourself (granted, it is not really trivial to write it yourself).  What is special about it is that it is standard, i.e. every standard conforming C++ compiler implementation since 1998 has support for it.

double-free error.

thanks, I will keep track of that

@mention PaulMcKenzie it's cool to use std::vector but as I am learning I love to do it from scratch, and after mastering the concepts this will allow me to use these stuff later in advance

Ok, I finally found the solution.
I have to create a copy constructor because if the compiler doesn't find a user-defined constructor, it sets it to default which will not modify our members like so:
(in Group class)
    Group(Group& source) : Group()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<source.length; i++)
            push(source.Items[i]);
    }

This is fine now but this will be tricky if you see line 1 in Group<Group<int>>::operator*(int) You should see that the pointer is using the assignment operator to swap the data so we should create one to our class ...
Or the compiler will do it.
(in Group class)
void operator=(Group& source)
    {
        length = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<source.length; i++)
            push(source.Items[i]);
    }

It is important to set Group<T>::length before starting to 0 otherwise it will contain garbage data.
So, it's great to solve your buggy code.
Be careful of the compiler, it can be cunning.

...No, those are wrong. You should accept the parameter by a const reference. The operator= must delete[] the existing items first. operator= should return Group & (return *this;). operator= should check for self-assignment (if (this == &source)) and do nothing in that case.

What a coincidence that I finally found the solution -- That "coincidence" is well-explained at the "rule of 3" link in the main comment section.

"This is fine now" -- Only because your push() implementation leaks memory. If you fix the memory leak, this copy constructor will cause problems.

Side note: take a look at the copy and swap idiom for a brutally simple, nigh-foolproof way to write the assignment operator. It's not always the most efficient approach, but it's an awesome starting place that I've  rarely had to replace with something faster.
